# Do spam filters care about the reputation of the "A" record

Tags: email, email-bounces

I have a domain set up and an email address hosted with a third party provider (Zoho).

Whenever I send an email from this domain (mostly just personal emails, no mass marketing or anything like that) it always goes to the spam filters of Outlook users.

So I contacted the email providers and they told me that it's because the IP address associated with my domains "A" record is triggering the spam filters.

I found this odd because from what I know, a major benefit of using a third party email provider is that you don't have to worry about the reputation of your own IP address. Also, from what I understand the MX records are all email providers care about when it comes to spam.

So, is it possible that Outlook is marking my emails as spam because my (DigitalOcean hosted) "A" record IP address for the domain has a bad reputation?

I found this similar question here: [Do mail servers and/or spam filters care about a domain's root A record?](https://serverfault.com/questions/332760/do-mail-servers-and-or-spam-filters-care-about-a-domains-root-a-record)

However, this is asking more about the presence of the record, and less so about the reputation of the IP associated with the record.

Comment: I don't know much about Digital Ocean's mail service but if it is software hosted on your own personal server / IP then the IP may have been resold and be carrying a bad reputation. If this is the IP of of Digital Ocean's private servers for an e-mail product that does sound wrong.

Comment: No sorry, the DigitalOcean IP is used to host my website, not emails (that's where the "A" record points to). The MX record points to a service called Zoho which has an email hosting platform

Comment: Most providers don't disclose the internal working of their spam filters, but the reason why your messages are delivered to Spam folders might be recorded in the message headers, so if you can request those it might help diagnose the issue. Generally though reliable email delivery from your own domain to the recipients inbox only requires that the mail related DNS records are set up correctly (MX, SPF, DKIM, DMARC, the reverse DNS record for the outgoing mail server etc.)  Unless your website is on a URI DNS blacklist and your messages link to your site, your A records should not matter.

Comment: An e-mail providers IP address should not be showing up on spam lists but Zoho looks fairly ropey to me and maybe that is happening, you can always check the IP online across various spam blacklists.